# Ear file does not include dependencies of sub-modules

Tags: java, maven, ejb, pom.xml, ear

Ear file does not include dependency of submodule in lib folder. I have following structure and the problem also give below.

```
Project module structure: 

- project-api   -> built as jar
   - has dependency A

- project-impl  -> built as jar
     has dependency B


- application -> built as ear
   - includes in its pom project-impl as dependency 
   - lib folder --------> does not include dependencies such as project-api and dependency B of project-impl in lib folder of ear file.
```

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Please add the full pom file or even better a link to a project on Github or alike...

Comment: I adjusted the pom of project-api, i.e. the scope from provided into compile and the problem was solved. Thanks.